# updating one dropdown updates every occurrence

Tags: jquery

jquery call

```
$("form[name='searchbox-purchase'] select[name='city']").change(function(){
});
```

i have 4 forms with following names

1. searchbox-purchase
2. searchbox-rental
3. searchbox-agents
4. searchbox-developments

each form has a dropdown with name 'city'.
i want if i change dropdown of searchbox-purchase form, only dropdown city in that particular form should be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want if i change dropdown of
>   searchbox-purchase form, only dropdown
>   city in that particular form should be
>   changed.

Your code is fine:

```
$("form[name='searchbox-purchase'] select[name='city']").change(function(){ 
});
```

You just specify same for all fours forms and it will affect only dropdown of those forms:

```
$("form[name='searchbox-purchase'] select[name='city']").change(function(){
   // this will affect city dropdown inside searchbox-purchase
});


$("form[name='searchbox-rental'] select[name='city']").change(function(){
   // this will affect city dropdown inside searchbox-rental
});


$("form[name='searchbox-agents'] select[name='city']").change(function(){
   // this will affect city dropdown inside searchbox-agents
});


$("form[name='searchbox-developments'] select[name='city']").change(function(){
   // this will affect city dropdown inside searchbox-developments
});
```

Comment: thanks for the info. My code for change event had a mistake. I was using
("select[name='location']")
instead of
("form[name='searchbox-purchase'] select[name='location']")

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give each of the dropdowns unique Id's and use those ids as selectors?

Comment: all of them are concerned to the city